# Custom WebApi AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following custom authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ActionsEnum Action;
    public bool State;

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        //Custom validation here...

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
    }
}
```

I also have this controller:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private bool canCreate, canUpdate, canDelete;

    public CustomerController()
    {
        //Dummy values
        canCreate = true;
        canUpdate = true;
        canDelete = false;
    }

    [CustomAuthorize(Action = ActionsEnum.Create, State = canCreate)]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(CustomerDTO customer)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PutCustomer(CustomerDTO customer)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        //Code...
    }
}
```

However, I get a compile error on 'State = canCreate':

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CustomerController.canCreate'

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables inside an attribute. Attributes need to have a static value at compile time. You could either set a static value to state:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Action = ActionsEnum.Create, State = true)]
```

Or get those values inside your attribute

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

    var canX = // Get value here
    //Custom validation here...

    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
}
```